# More efficient way to do this in GLSL

Tags: opengl, optimization, glsl

```
x += offset * vec3(notEqual(a, greaterThanEqual(fract(b), vec3(0.5))));
```

x and b are vector3, and a is bvec3.

This seems fairly expensive and i'm wondering if there is another way to do it. Basically I want to offset x component wise by a fixed amount depending on if b's fractional component is above 0.5, and if a is 1 or 0 (true or false). If it's 1 and <0.5, do an offset, if it's 0 and >0.5 do an offset, like xor, I use notEqual for xor here.

Comment: Your best bet is to see what performance you can get from various different options. On current hardware, I wouldn't be surprised if a simple `if' statement turned out to be the best solution.

Comment: @fintelia: Since the condition is per component, wouldn't you need 3 if statements? Benchmarking different options is definitely the right thing to do, but I wouldn't place my bets on a solution that uses 3 if statements.

Comment: I wonder if the statement in its current form is actually "fairly expensive". I wouldn't bet on the `if` statement, too. It is unclear what the context of this is, but if a or b are actually not dynamically uniform expressions, introducing non-uniform control flow will very likely make things worse, even on the newest GPU generation.

Comment: how about something like `int x += offset * (1 - int(step(fract(b), 0.5)) ^ a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of anything massively better. This one looks slightly simpler than what you have:

```
x += offset * vec3(notEqual(vec3(a), round(fract(b))));
```

Or similarly:

```
x += offset * vec3(notEqual(vec3(a), step(0.5, fract(b))));
```

If the `notEqual()` is expensive, the xor-type operation could be replaced by using a sum modulo 2:

```
x += offset * mod(vec3(a) + round(fract(b)), 2.0);
```

Or in a similar spirit, but avoiding the `mod()` at the price of a few more basic operations:

```
vec3 af = vec3(a);
vec3 brf = round(fract(b));
x += offset * (af + brf - 2.0 * af * brf);
```

There's probably countless more variations and permutations of similar ideas. As was already suggested in the comments, there's almost no way around benchmarking them on a good cross-section of the hardware you care about.